# Install Neurolab for Python 3.11

Tags: python, machine-learning, anaconda, neurolab

I´m trying to install the `neurolab` package to my `Python 3.11` environment.
I use `Anaconda` with `Python version 3.11`. The available versions of `Neurolab` found on `Anaconda` page are those:

[image]

But none of this versions work on `Python 3.11` . I tried to instal via `Anaconda Navigator` and `CMD (I use Windows 11)`.

How to install this package (or a similar version that works) with my version of Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pip install neurolab
```

After you create and activate a conda environment